# failed to set parent for annotation in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, user-interface, annotations, parent

I have created a figure in MATLAB, and an axis inside the figure. 
I want to have annotation in the axis, so that it would be easier for me to define its relative position.

But I failed when I use

```
numRec = annotation('rectangle','Parent', app.DisplayPath)
```

where the app.DisplayPath is the axis I mentioned above.

The console gives the following warning

> Warning: Cannot specify the parent of an annotation object - Ignoring
>   the parent property

I am wondering if there is anyway I could set the annotation's parent as the axis? I find that annotation has property of Parent on documentation, but it says:

> Parent: [1x1 AnnotationPane]

Any hints are appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

If you read [the documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/annotation.html) you will see that annotations are children of a `figure`, `uipanel`, or `uiobject` only. You can specify between these using the [`'Container'` property](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/annotation.html#namevaluepairarguments) of the annotation object.

> `annotation(container,___)` creates the annotation in the figure, uipanel, or uitab specified by container, instead of in the current figure.

Comment: Thanks, I have tried that first, but no rectangular annotation displays in my axis. That's why I change to other ways. I already have a image displayed in the axis, is it the reason why my rectangular annotation is 'hidden'?